# Maven build keeps failing in Concourse Pipeline with a "Forked VM termination error"

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin, concourse, concourse-pipeline

So, I assembled a concourse pipeline that fetches a ([repo](https://github.com/jdecoroso/cocas.git)) and runs a pretty basic Spring project (**maven install** goal).

Whenever the task starts, it mostly immediately fails with the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.1.2:test (default-test) on project gs-maven: 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /tmp/build/69a7d209/source-code/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was /bin/sh -c cd '/tmp/build/69a7d209/source-code' && '/opt/java/openjdk/bin/java' 'org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter' '/tmp/build/69a7d209/source-code/target/surefire' '2023-10-03T10-46-11_322-jvmRun1' 'surefire-20231003104612119_1tmp' 'surefire_0-20231003104612119_2tmp'
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Error while executing forked tests.Error while executing process.Cannot run program "/bin/sh" (in directory "/tmp/build/69a7d209/source-code"): error=0, Failed to exec spawn helper: pid: 5579, exit value: 1org.apache.maven.surefire.shared.utils.cli.CommandLineException: Error while executing process.
```

The strangest thing (to me) is that I can run the same goal locally, or in a docker container from the same maven:latest image, so it seems to be pretty much a concourse issue.

The concourse job/task details are as follow:

```
resources:
  - name: source-code
    type: git
    source:
      uri: https://github.com/jdecoroso/cocas.git
      branch: main

jobs:
  - name: systest-validation
    public: true
    plan:
      - get: source-code
        trigger: true
      - task: run-system-tests
        config:
      # Tells Concourse which type of worker this task should run on
          platform: linux
      # This is one way of telling Concourse which container image to use for a
          image_resource:
            type: registry-image
            source:
              repository: maven
              tag: latest
          inputs:
            - name: source-code
      # The command Concourse will run inside the container
          run:
            path: /bin/bash
            args:
              - -c
              - |
                  cd source-code
                  mvn -f pom.xml install
```

The actual results should have been a successful Maven build execution